# T-SQL, get value from xml in a column

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have a table with an XML column (xmlCol) and I am trying to query a value from it.

Here's the xml.

```
<criteria>
  <factor name="Rivers" title="Rivers">
    <value dataType="Int32" value="1743" description="Wilson0" />
  </factor>
  <factor name="OptionalAffProperties" title="Include properties">
    <value dataType="String" value="FishingModel" description="Fishing Model" />
  </factor>
</criteria>
```

Here is a select to get the column.  select xmlCol from MyTable

I am trying to return the value 1743 to a column called RiverID.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
    xmlCol.value('(//factor[@name="Rivers"]/value/@value)[1]', 'int') As RiverID
FROM
    MyTable
```

[value() Method (xml Data Type) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)
[XQuery Language Reference (SQL Server) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Austin Good spot! Fixed.

Comment: `/criteria/factor` will be faster than `//factor`

Answer (score 1):

To get the attribute value, you can query it like so:

```
select xmlCol.value('(/criteria/factor/value/@value)[1]', 'int') RiverID
from MyTable
```

You provide the xml path to the record you are looking for: `(/criteria/factor/value`

And then the attribute you need: `/@value)[1]`.